# Splicing elements out of a Vector in a loop which goes through the same Vector (ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, vector, collision-detection

I'm making a simple game and have a Vector full of enemies in order to do hit-checking on them from my "laser" object (it's a space shmup). Every laser loops through the Vector and checks if it's occluding the hit circle. The problem lies in when one laser destroys an enemy, the rest of the lasers try to also check the same Vector, only to go out of bounds since the enemy's already been spliced out and it's changed the size of the Vector.

```
for each (var enemy:Enemy in enemies){
                var distanceX = this.x - enemy.x;
                var distanceY = this.y - enemy.y;
                var distance = Math.sqrt( (distanceX*distanceX) + (distanceY*distanceY) );

                if (distance <= enemy.hitRadius) {
                    enemy.removeEnemy();
                    enemies.splice(enemies.indexOf(enemy),enemies.indexOf(enemy));
                }
}
```

How would I go about collecting the index of individual elements in the Vector to be deleted, then only deleting them when every Laser object is finished its checking?

edit: here's my removeEnemy() function from my Enemy class, just in case:

```
public function removeEnemy(){
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
            parent.removeChild(this);
            trace("removed Enemy", enemies.indexOf(this));
        }
```

edit edit: I'm also getting a null reference pointer error to "parent" in my removeEnemy() function... but only sometimes. I have a feeling that if I fix one of these two problems, the other will also be fixed but I'm not sure.

Comment: what about while the lasers are checking the Vector, if one hits... just mark the enemy as hit.  Then when all lasers have performed their checks, have a final run to remove all that are marked "hit".

Comment: The thing is that the hit checking is in the Laser object itself, which is more or less unreferenced in the code; I was hoping to avoid having to keep another Vector/Array of laser objects and have them simply deal with themselves, but if there's no better way I guess I could keep an array of the lasers.

Isn't there a way to scan through all the children of the stage and get their references and use that as an array? I could see for each (var laser:Laser in stage) being a good way to go through them all, and it might be a bit faster.

Comment: code corner.. :) fun.  I guess you could look for the lasers.  But, there is more on the stage than lasers so do something like laser = stage[item] as Laser;  then say if(laser) (this will be null if the item isn't a laser)

Comment: @EricDand you should follow Jason's suggestion you're better off having a concise list of the elements you need to deal with than trying to traverse a tree and doing comparisons along the way, you're storing references not copies so you're not losing much memory by making an array.

Comment: I fixed it. Read my answer for how. I'm such an idiot.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll definitely implement the first one-- the number of enemies often gets into the hundreds and although it works just fine now, I could see it getting slow when I add all sorts of other features. Refactoring just for refactoring's sake is also always a good move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! The problem was actually in how I used the "splice()" method. Turns out that the second parameter isn't the end index of where to stop splicing, it's the number of elements to be spliced. So when I was trying to splice element 0, I wasn't splicing anything, and when I was trying to splice element 3, I was also splicing 4 and 5. I feel like such a dunce for not reading the API right and wasting a couple hours on this. Thanks to everyone who commented-- you guys helped me rule out what I thought the problem was.